# Cygrunsrv & autossh : A way to embedd remote commands in the command line?

Tags: ssh, cygwin, tunnel

I'm using cygrunsrv and autossh on windows XP to create a service building a tunnel to a remote server but i also want to create another tunnel from the remote server to another server.

I can achieve it with this command line :

```
autossh -M 5432 serverA -t 'autossh -M 4321 serverB -N'
```

but when I want to set it up in cygwin through cygrunsrv to make it works as a service :

```
cygrunsrv -I TUNNEL -p /usr/bin/autossh -a "-M 5432 serverA -t 'autossh -M 4321 serverB -N'" -e AUTOSSH_NTSERVICE=yes -e AUTOSSH_POLL=20 -e AUTOSSH_GATETIME=30
```

It's not fully working. The service is creating the tunnel correctly to ServerA but it's not sending the autossh command "autossh -M 4321 serverB -N" to ServerA.
I tried to escape the quote but all my efforts didn't make any difference and I'm not seeing any command sent in the autossh logs.

I think the problem is related to pseudo terminal that is not created through the cygrunsrv.

I'd like to know if there's a way to fix my cygrunsrv command line to make it work or should I consider a different approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lionel, try removing the `AUTOSSH_NTSERVICE=yes` from the cygrunsrv invocation.  As /usr/share/doc/autossh/README.Cygwin explains:

> Setting AUTOSSH_NTSERVICE=yes in the calling environment ...
>   change[s] autossh's behavior in three useful
>   ways:
>
> (1) Add an -N flag to each invocation of ssh, thus disabling shell
>   access.  The idea is that if you're running autossh as a system
>   service, you're using it to forward ports; it wouldn't make sense to
>   run a shell session as a system service.  (If you think this reasoning
>   is wrong, please send a bug report to the author or Cygwin maintainer,
>   and tell us what you're trying to do.)

Despite what the above says, it seems that you may have a good reason for not wanting `-N` (which suppresses command execution) in your service's ssh invocation.  Removing `AUTOSSH_NTSERVICE=yes` should take care of it.  It will have a couple of other minor disadvantages, but you can probably live with it.  Read the rest of README.Cygwin for the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew, I removed the AUTOSSH_NTSERVICE=yes in my command line and it worked.I believed it was a necessary option as it was loaded as a service and I obviously missed the -N flag note in the readme that disabled the shell access, blocking my second autossh call to be sent.

Comment: Thanks again for you time and documented answer. Have a great day !